# Zurb Foundation columns in div.row are not collapsing

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I am having a problem with Foundation 5 where I am trying to get the columns in a row div to have collapsed gutters. More specifically, I am interested in collapsing the outer column gutters so that my nav bar and header div will line up nicely. I tried applying the .collapse class to the containing row div as well as to each column element, to no avail.

If anyone could help me figure out what I am missing, I would really appreciate it! Below is the code for the problem section of the page and a screen cap so you can see what I am trying to accomplish.

Ultimately I want to create a narrow vertical strip on either side of the page with a transitional gradient (blue to grey). If it is possible to do this in in the gutter, that would be a good solution to my problem as well. Thanks in advance!

```
  <!-- Header Image and Left Side Nav Links -->

  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="header-image">
      <nav class="top-bar-z top-bar large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="is_hover:false">
        <ul class="title-area">
          <li class="name">
            <h1>
              <a href="#">Lacmhacarh</a>
            </h1>
          </li>
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Right Side Nav Links -->
        <section class="top-bar-section">
          <ul class="right">
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">Blog</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">See all →</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Résumé<i class="fi-play"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.github.com/danielbonnell">GitHub</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/danielbonnell">LinkedIn</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/acidstealth">Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><label>Special Projects</label></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.abhnation.com/">The Abh Nation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something Cool Here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </nav>

      <!-- Header Foreground Image -->
      <div class="large-4 columns">
        <div class="header-logo-left">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 columns">
        <div class="header-logo-center">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 columns">
        <div class="header-logo-right">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After re-examining the code I figured out that the column gutters are not the problem causing the apparent offset in the right edge of the nav-bar. I had placed an extra divider after the "Contact" button, which was adding 10px of space.

Here is the original HTML for that part of the nav-bar:

```
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
```

And the new code:

```
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in order for .collapse to work, the .columns must be the first child div of the row.

```html
<div class="row collapse">
  <div class="large-12 columns"> <!--gets collapsed-->
    Collapsed?
    </div>
  </div>
```